# StopWatch Class with methods

Tags: java, math, for-loop, stopwatch

Alright so I'm still kind of new with methods so forgive me if this seems out of whack. I have a homework problem that has to be a stop watch class with two private data fields startTime and endTime. I need a method named start() that resets startTime to the current time and then stop() that resets endTime to the current time. I also need a getElapsed time method and returns the value.
This is what I got so far:

```
public class stopWatch {
    private double startTime;
    private double endTime;

public static void main(String[]args) {

}

public stopWatch(double startTime) {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void start() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

} 

public void stop() {
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public static void getElapsedTime(double startTime, double endTime){
    stop() - start()

}
}
```

Could anybody please send me a step in the right direction? I know i need to subtract the start time from the stopped time and return that as the elapsed, I'm just not sure how to set it up properly.

Comment: Be more precise, this is a Q&A not a help forum. Tell us what you have done and where exactly you encounter problems.

Answer (score 2):

Couple points.

- startTime and endTime should be longs
- Constructor should probably not take an argument.
- start should probably set `endTime` to -1
- `getElapsedTime` should be an instance method, not take arguments, return `long` and return `endTime - startTime`
- to see it work, in your main, create a stopwatch, start the timer, call Thread.sleep(sometime), call stop, print out getElapsed.

Comment: "Constructor should probably not take an argument." it definitly shouldn't as they will just disapear with the code he wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create the exact same thing. I wanted a simple Java stopwatch that would start running on my desktop. This is the code from the Stopwatch class. I added some formatting so it doesn't return long numbers that show how many milliseconds since you started the stopwatch. I assume that you would prefer to get something returned that is more meaningful to humans like seconds, minutes, and hours instead of milliseconds.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Stopwatch
{
    // variables
    private long startTime;
    DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("00");     // These help me return strings in the correct format
    DecimalFormat threeDigits = new DecimalFormat("000");  // These help me return strings in the correct format

    // Constructor
    Stopwatch()
    {
    }

    void start()
    {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public long getStartTime()
    {
        return startTime;
    }

    public long getElapsedTime()
    {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    }

    public String getElapsedTimeString()
    {
        return (String.valueOf(twoDigits.format(getHours())) + ":" + String.valueOf(twoDigits.format(getMinutes())) + ":" + String.valueOf(twoDigits.format(getSeconds())) + "." + String.valueOf(threeDigits.format(getMilliSeconds())));
    }

    public short getMilliSeconds()
    {
        return (short)((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) % 1000);
    }

    public byte getSeconds()
    {
        return (byte)(((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) % 60);
    }

    public byte getMinutes()
    {
        return (byte)(((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 60000) % 60);
    }
    public long getHours()
    {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 3600000;
    }
}
```